# How to type " ----- insert text -----" in HTML?

Tags: html

Similar to how you would get a solid line using multiple underscores, is there a way in HTML to write "-------" without the dashes? Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: is it required to use dashes or you can use css also? In css you can use `border` property

Comment: @S4beR doesn't matter, css works. Oriol answered it and told me about line-drawing. Never knew about box-drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [line-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character):

```html
───────────── foo ━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the html `<hr>` element for a horizontal line but you will need to write a seperate html element and place it on top of that line for the text.